# replace string with spaces in origin string

Tags: string, sed, replace, space

I'm trying to replace a string like `\\server\share\doc share\PDF` with something like `\\server2\share\client\01-client-doc\00-verified\PDF` .

First step im playing only with 1 file, then I'll change all the rest.

This is the exact command I'm using.

```
sed -i -e 's/server\share\doc share\PDF/server2\share\client\01-client-doc\00-verified\PDF/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Using `#` instead of `/`

Answer (score 0):

You need protect your `\` on the other hand `\s` means `whitespaces` (tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space)

```
sed -i -e 's/server\\share\\doc share\\PDF/server2\\share\\client\\01-client-doc\\00-verified\\PDF/g' file.txt
```